# how to find the latest element from the group of nodes where the attribute of the element represents the date and time. in xml

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, xml

```
<data>

  <manufacture  date="2013-06-05 T 19:40:50. 88463 7 Z">
    <title>java_package</title>
    <author>tom</author>
    <year>2013</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </manufacture>

  <manufacture  date="2015-06-05T19:40:50.884637Z">
    <title>java_package_2</title>
    <author>tom</author>
    <year>2015</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </manufacture>

 <manufacture  date="2014-06-05T19:40:50.884637Z">
    <title>java_package_3</title>
    <author>tom</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </manufacture>

</data>
```

DATA is the root element, Manufacture is the element content. 
here i need to get the latest manufacture, based on date i.e

> 2015-06-05 T 19 : 40 : 50 . 88463 7 Z

which is an attribute of the manufacture element.

i am doing in asp.net and c#

here is my code that i tried

```
 XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                xdoc.LoadXml("bc.xml");
                XmlNode root = xdoc.DocumentElement;
              XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//manufacture");

            foreach (XmlNode node1 in nodeList)
                {

                    Label1.Text +=  node.Attributes["DATE"].Value.ToString() + "\n <br>";

                }
```

Comment: Im confused - are you trying to do this in JavaScript or c#? Also, where is the code that shows what you have tried?

Comment: XmlNodeList nodeList3 = root.SelectNodes("//manufacture");

Answer (score 0):

Your datetime formatting in the file is wrong and inconsistent....
It should be like this : "2013-06-05 T19:40:50.884637Z" otherwise any and every code will fail...

Here is the solution...

```
var mf = doc.Root.Elements("manufacture")
        .OrderByDescending (m => DateTime.ParseExact(m.Attribute("date").Value, "yyyy-MM-dd THH:mm:ss.ffffffZ", null))
        .First();
```